# RobotFramework : cx_Oracle - FAIL : InternalError: No Oracle error?

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle, robotframework

Couldn't find a solution for my problem using search so I created this topic.

I'm having problems when connecting to Oracle database using [DataBase libary](http://franz-see.github.com/Robotframework-Database-Library/) and cx_Oracle module.

In python `import cx_Oracle` works great (returns no error), but when I try to connect to DB on RobotFramework with `Connect To Database Using Custom Params | cx_Oracle | 'user', 'pass', 'host/db'`

I get an error : `FAIL : InternalError: No Oracle error?`

If I try to connect to database using

```
Connect To Database | dbapiModuleName=cx_Oracle | dbName=db_name | dbUsername=user | dbPassword=pass | dbHost=host | dbPort=port
```

I get an error : `FAIL : TypeError: 'database' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

I'm using Windows7 x86, non-Administrator user, Oracle 11g, Python 2.7.3, cx_Oracle 5.1.2, RobotFramework 2.7.6, RIDE 1.0.1. Everything else works like a charm (connection to database using PLSQLDeveloper, RobotFramework, Selenium2Libary etc.)

Have anyone any ideas how can I solve my problem?

Sincerely,
Kristiāns

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem: 'FAIL : TypeError: 'database' is an invalid keyword argument for this function'

This is what works for me:

```
DatabaseLibrary.Connect To Database Using Custom Params | cx_Oracle | 'user', 'password', 'host:port/dbname'
```