# how to connect oracle database to robot framework

Tags: database, oracle, robotframework

Dose anyone know connection between oracle and robot framework? how to import oracle database to robot framework? any documentation can help me to understand these two? how does it link? 
my main objective is to compare the type of db, one is oracle, other is SQL, compare these two bds using robot framework. right now, i don't know how to connect oracle db to robot framework, thanks!

Here is the solutinon. dns:ip address: port NO./ database location

Comment: [That](http://robotframework.org/) RobotFramework? AFAIK this is "only" a test framework. Does it really use a RDBMS to store tests/test results ? Or is the DB part of the "tested" application ? Or are you planing to "test your DB" ? May I suggest you to take some time to edit you question to provide a little bit of context -- and to clearly explain the issue you're trying to solve ?

Comment: hi i have edited a bit, hope it will help others to understand me better, thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to databases with Robot Framework, you can use the [Database Library](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/) in conjunction with [cx_oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) (Python lib to connect to Oracle DB). Try this out and if you get stuck, come back with more detailed questions with pieces of code, errors etc. please. (By the way, here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019323/robotframework-cx-oracle-fail-internalerror-no-oracle-error) related to your request that might help you)

Comment: this is an error: "FAIL DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified" I think i did not connect to oracle db, because my db is at remote desk, how do i link to remote desk (i actually did put my variables as userName, Password, and Ip for remotedesk) not sure I am doing the right way

Comment: i tried to try to connect but error showed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1), anyone undersandn what does it  mean?